# How can i send a variable from a method to the catch block of that caller's method in c#?

Tags: c#, variables, exception

Let's say I have a method like this.

```
Boolean hasErrors = false;
try
{
    var anotherId = DoSomethingWithList(list);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    errorMessageDetail.Text = ex.Message;
    hasErrors = true;
}
```

And In my `DoSomethingWithList` method I am doing fancy stuff in an iteration.

```
public Guid? DoSomethingWithList(List<ofthings> myList)
{
    foreach (var member in myList)
    {
          //Do fancy and dangerous stuff in here.
    }
}
```

What I try to achieve is that, When I get an exception in `DoSomethingWithList` method I also want to know in which member of the list this exception has been thrown, and include it in `errorMessageDetail`. Thank you in advance.

Edit: I can not simply move my exception block into the loop itself because `errorMessageDetail` is connected with the aspx in the front end, and my `DoSomethingWithList` method is in my Business Layer.

Comment: Then put the try/catch block inside the loop. Rethrow a detailed exception.

Comment: you would like to make custom exception to include "the member of the list which caused an exception" .

Comment: You shouldn't be coding failure with an exception. Exceptions should be for exceptional circumstances. Catch and deal with those exceptions - don't just let them bubble up and catch with a general purpose exception handler.

Comment: If it's *reasonable* to be exposing exception details to your users (and you need to consider that question carefully rather than just assuming it is) then please use `ToString()` rather than `Message`, so that you *are* providing details including a stack trace rather than just one bare message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
public Guid? DoSomethingWithList(List<ofthings> myList){
foreach (var member in myList){
    try{
      //Do fancy and dangerous stuff in here.
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} thrown by {1}", e.Message, member.ToString()), e);    
    }
}
```

I'm assuming member has a suitable implementation of ToString(), otherwise just use whatever property is relevant.

Comment: There's no need to call `ToString()` on something that you're passing as an argument to `string.Format`. It's already going to do that for you.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever fair comment but it gave me something on which to hang my comment about there being a suitable implementation of it.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. Actually @Stefan's reply is good also but this reply is simpler for me to implement and gives me the exact same thing that I wanted in my code. This was executed in a file input for the rows of an excel file and I have just replaced `member.toString()` to an integer variable i used as a counterof rows. So the output message has become something like `you have an error on line {myCounter} ` :)

Answer (score 2):

You could create your specific exception type. E.g.

```
public Guid? DoSomethingWithList(List<ofthings> myList)
{
    foreach (var member in myList)
    {
        try
        {
          //Do fancy and dangerous stuff in here.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             throw new ListProcessingException(member, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the only way to return state from `DoSomethingWithList` in case of error is to wrap its functionality in another try catch as @Stefan Steinegger said.

because if you dont catch the exception the (thread / callstack) will be killed and thus stack frames will be dead.
(stack frame is where locals are stored)